# adb logcat not attaching to device on nativescript application

Tags: android, adb, nativescript, nativescript-vue, vue-devtools

I run `tns run android --hmr` which opens my app on my phone

Then `adb usb` and get notification on my phone that usb logging is connected.

Then `tns device log`

Then `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`

Then `adb logcat`

But I don't get anything displayed.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Does `adb devices` return the list of devices? Sometimes you may have to restart the service couple times before it detects the device properly.

Comment: @Manoj turned out this was the issue. https://superuser.com/questions/1357708/android-adb-logcat-works-only-on-shell